# what does "laser-target" mean

Tags: phrases

In this sentence "because Amazon Suggest keywords are so laser-targeted, they tend to convert great.", what does "laser-target" mean?

Comment: Have you googled the expression?

Answer (score 0):

***Laser*** is used in combination with other words as an intensifier, like in *laser-focused* for instance.

***Laser-targeted*** means carefully and precisely targeted on specific markets, issues, strategies etc.

Examples:

- [5 Strategies for Facebook Ad Targeting With Laser Precision](https://smallbiztrends.com/2015/01/5-strategies-for-facebook-ad-targeting-with-laser-precision.html)
- [How To Use Social Networks To Create Laser-Targeted B2B Advertising Campaigns](https://searchengineland.com/how-to-use-social-networks-to-create-laser-targeted-b2b-advertising-campaigns-147554)

Answer (score 0):

A **laser** is best known for being a very precise and narrow beam of light. Terms such as "laser-guided precision", whether being literal or not, make use of this fact.

In your sentence, Amazon are merely stating that their suggested keywords are very precise for the user.